# Searching for file in current directory with particular extension in C

Tags: c, standard-library

Is there any function in a standard C library which allow one to retrieve files with a particular extension like ".c"?

Comment: short answer is no. what is your OS?

Comment: @jev Its linux debian

Comment: you can us the `exec` family of functions to call the usual unix utils (ls, grep etc)

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Calling-Glob

Comment: `system("find ...");`

Comment: @Shahzad: Do it need to be portable?

Answer (score 0):

There are no standard C library functions that do that.  There are platform-specific functions that do that.

EDIT:  If you're on Debian, try looking up the documentation for `glob` or `wordexp`.  The documentation for `glob` even has an example, looking up `.c` files, just as you wish.